# Where do I set the quota for my appengine app

Tags: google-app-engine

For some strange reason, my app seems to give 503 error, saying it went over quata. Where do I set the quota to be higher. I can pay the extra money, but I can't find how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable **billing** for your applications. Please refer to the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing) and the [first question](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#resources) in the FAQ addresses your point.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a serivce wide problem. Got it fixed.